# apply css style to bx-slider element

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have applied to my site jquery effect bx-slider  [Bx-Slider Page](http://bxslider.com/) but now I would apply to prev and next arrow my css. I applied to it images but I would even apply css propriety.
here it is a piece of jquery.bxslide.js code:

```
var defaults = {
        mode: 'horizontal',                                 // 'horizontal', 'vertical', 'fade'
        infiniteLoop: true,                                 // true, false - display first slide after last
        hideControlOnEnd: false,                        // true, false - if true, will hide 'next' control on last slide and 'prev' control on first
        controls: true,                                         // true, false - previous and next controls
        speed: 700,                                                 // integer - in ms, duration of time slide transitions will occupy
        easing: 'swing',                    // used with jquery.easing.1.3.js - see http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ for available options
        pager: false,                                               // true / false - display a pager
        pagerSelector: null,                                // jQuery selector - element to contain the pager. ex: '#pager'
        pagerType: 'full',                                  // 'full', 'short' - if 'full' pager displays 1,2,3... if 'short' pager displays 1 / 4
        pagerLocation: 'bottom',                        // 'bottom', 'top' - location of pager
        pagerShortSeparator: '/',                       // string - ex: 'of' pager would display 1 of 4
        pagerActiveClass: 'pager-active',       // string - classname attached to the active pager link
        nextText: '',                                       // string - text displayed for 'next' control
        nextImage: 'images/right_arrow.png',                                            // string - filepath of image used for 'next' control. ex: 'images/next.jpg'
        nextSelector: null,                                 // jQuery selector - element to contain the next control. ex: '#next'
        prevText: '',                                       // string - text displayed for 'previous' control
        prevImage: 'images/left_arrow.png',                                         // string - filepath of image used for 'previous' control. ex: 'images/prev.jpg'
        prevSelector: null,                                 // jQuery selector - element to contain the previous control. ex: '#next'
        captions: false,                                        // true, false - display image captions (reads the image 'title' tag)
        captionsSelector: null,                         // jQuery selector - element to contain the captions. ex: '#captions'
        auto: false,                                                // true, false - make slideshow change automatically
        autoDirection: 'next',                          // 'next', 'prev' - direction in which auto show will traverse
        autoControls: false,                                // true, false - show 'start' and 'stop' controls for auto show
        autoControlsSelector: null,                 // jQuery selector - element to contain the auto controls. ex: '#auto-controls'
        autoStart: true,                                        // true, false - if false show will wait for 'start' control to activate
        autoHover: false,                                       // true, false - if true show will pause on mouseover
        autoDelay: 0,                       // integer - in ms, the amount of time before starting the auto show
        pause: 3000,                                                // integer - in ms, the duration between each slide transition
        startText: 'start',                                 // string - text displayed for 'start' control
        startImage: '',                                         // string - filepath of image used for 'start' control. ex: 'images/start.jpg'
        stopText: 'stop',                                       // string - text displayed for 'stop' control
        stopImage: '',                                          // string - filepath of image used for 'stop' control. ex: 'images/stop.jpg'
        ticker: false,
```

As you can read, you have to set next/prev selector to control but when I set a selector my controls vanished.why?

Comment: That piece of code you posted does not help. You should post your actual css/js code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enter the elements you would like to the jQuery on the page where your slider is.

So if your slider is on index.html open that page and find the following code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
  });
});
```

and put the elements you want within this. So to add your arrow images for next and prev your could would be

```
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  $('#slider1').bxSlider({
    nextImage: 'url of image goes here',
    prevImage: 'url of image goes here',
    prevText: '',   
    nextText: '',
  });
});
```

I also added the 'prevText' and nextText and left them blank otherwise both the images and the text show for me.

Hope that Helps
ThreeTwo